# How to correctly setup NSNotification and post?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to make a singleton Reachability observer for each connection delegate to use,
however I couldn't build it correctly, here is some snippet of code.

MYReachability.m

```
static MYReachability *sharedInstance;

+ (MYReachability *)sharedInstance
{
    if (sharedInstance == NULL) {
        sharedInstance = [[MYReachability alloc] init];
    }

    return sharedInstance;
}

- (void)addReachabilityObserver
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self
                                             selector: @selector(reachabilityChanged:)
                                                 name: kReachabilityChangedNotification
                                               object: nil];

    Reachability *reach = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostname: @"www.apple.com"];
    [reach startNotifier];
}

- (void) reachabilityChanged: (NSNotification *)notification {
    NSLog(@"notification: %@", notification);
    Reachability *reach = [notification object];

    if( [reach isKindOfClass: [Reachability class]]) {
        NetworkStatus status = [reach currentReachabilityStatus];
        NSLog(@"reachability status: %u", status);
        if (status == NotReachable) {
            // Insert your code here
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                            message:@"Cannot connect to server..."
                                                           delegate:nil
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
        }
    }
}
```

in MYConnectionDelegate.m

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    if (error.code) {
        // sending notification to viewController
        [[MYReachability sharedInstance] addReachabilityObserver];
        MYTestClass *myTestClass = [MYTestClass new];
        [myTestClass notificationTrigger];
    }
}
```

in MYTestClass.m

```
- (void)notificationTrigger
{
    // All instances of TestClass will be notified
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     postNotificationName:kReachabilityChangedNotification
     object:self];
}
```

Rick, Thanks, that works, but here comes another problem,
each time it calls will generates one more notifications into stack...
I made a dealloc in MYReachability.m

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
```

but previous notification still exists.

Comment: What stack are you talking about? when you send a notification the code to execute is only run once. Do you mean there are more than one observers? By the way what are you trying to achieve by placing that code in the dealloc? By the way that is not how you create a singleton.

Comment: Yes, the alertView will show up more than one time, as many as it triggers times of number, seems like previous notification does not release.

Comment: Shouldn't `== NULL` be better written as `== nil`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling the method `notificationTrigger` but your test class only has the method `notificationTrigger:` with a colon, i.e. one parameter.

Change `[myTestClass notificationTrigger];` to `[myTestClass notificationTrigger:self];` and it should work.

If you only want the notification to show once, remove yourself as an observer once the alert view has been shown, like this:

```
- (void) reachabilityChanged: (NSNotification *)notification {
NSLog(@"notification: %@", notification);
Reachability *reach = [notification object];

if( [reach isKindOfClass: [Reachability class]]) {
    NetworkStatus status = [reach currentReachabilityStatus];
    NSLog(@"reachability status: %u", status);
    if (status == NotReachable) {
        // Insert your code here
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Cannot connect to server..." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Or [myTestClass notificationTrigger:self]; since its supposed to be the sender in case he wants to use it later on.

Answer (score 2):

In one class:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"notifyMe" object:self];
```

In another class:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(doSomething)
                                             name:@"notifyMe"
                                           object:nil];
```